# Laravel Eager-loading works only when calling attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I've defined my Slot model to load the relations from User model like so :

```
public function userAssignedFull(): HasOne {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_assigned');
}
```

('slots' table contains 'user_assigned' field by which I connect to User records on 'id')

The following code finds Slot model but without 'userAssignedFull'. I get only the user ID in 'user_assigned'.

```
  $slot = Slot::with('userAssignedFull')->find($slot_id);
```

But calling this afterward returns me the wanted relation:

```
$fullUserModel = $slot->userAssignedFull;
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Builder::with()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with) returns the [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) instance.

So you have to call `$slot->userAssignedFull;` to get the collection of data.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship **data is not**
>   **actually loaded until you first access the property**.

And this `$slot->userAssignedFull;` is your *"first access the property"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$slot = Slot::where('id', $slot_id)->with('userAssignedFull')->first();
$slot->userAssignedFull;
```